# How can I make magit aware of an upstream branch?

Tags: magit

I have a preexisting (github) repository with 2 branches: master and release. I successfully set my own local copy of the master branch to origin/master but when I try to set the release branch (using magit-branch-and-checkout), there is no origin/release option. The repository was initialized with magit-init, as it's a local copy.

Comment: If you type `f` followed by `u` in the Magit status buffer should download branch info from remote, then `b` followed by `c` to start a new branch, and when prompted for a starting point try `origin/release` (if it knows about it it will even auto-complete)